# Should I parallel unbuffered inverters in a CMOS crystal oscillator circuit?

Tags: oscillator, cmos, crystal

I want to use a 74HCU04 unbuffered inverter oscillator circuit as a digital clock source on a PCB, as referenced in this TI app note:
[Appnote SZZA043](https://www.ti.com/lit/an/szza043/szza043.pdf?ts=1690898442976&ref_url=https%253A%252F%252Fwww.google.com%252F)

It's mentioned in the note, the inverter gain is lower than a buffered inverter, the output is not a square wave, and it's suggested to run the output into a Schmidt trigger input. However, I am trying to keep the parts count low and don't want to add a Schmidt just for that. Also I'm running at 21MHz so I'm leery of the custom resistor network based Schmidt circuit using inverters that is shown there, for my application.

So my question, it occurred to me that all the inverters on a die have a very similar transfer characteristic, I could improve the gain element drive capability by parallelling 2 or more inverters on the hex inverter IC. Then, although the output wouldn't be a perfect square wave, at least it would be "more square" since it would drive the capacitive load of the feedback circuit better.

Am I crazy? Well, okay maybe I am but then, is this a good idea? or has little merit?

e.g.
[image]

Comment: Do you mean, paralleling more gates for driving the crystal itself, or, paralleling more gates when buffering the crystal signal out from the oscillator? Please draw a diagram.

Comment: Sorry, of course a diagram for this... by the way, the output goes to a single 74HC74 clock input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *Then, although the output wouldn't be a perfect square wave, at least
> it would be "more square" since it would drive the capacitive load of
> the feedback circuit better.*

You might be missing the point of the "output" capacitor (C2 in your circuit) and, trying to "fix" something that will come back to bite you in terms of frequency stability, ability to start, power-limiting the crystal and accuracy.

C2 is **intentionally** placed there to add maybe 10 to 30 more degrees phase shift. It creates this phase shift because the gate has a non-zero output resistance of tens to hundreds of ohms. Thus, "around the loop" there is an extra phase shift. R3 also helps this process.

The crystal and the capacitor at the input to the gate (C1 on your circuit) cannot quite produce a phase shift of 180° and, a helping hand is needed to push it past the winning post. That comes from the gate's output impedance, R3 and C2.

R3 might be enough of course but, the circuit may still be relying on the gate output limiting the power driven into the crystal. Having two gates at the input doubles the input capacitance and will also offset the frequency of your oscillator.

Comment: Oh, so at least the TI suggestions for choosing a value for R3 become inapplicable. When you add the extra gate, you are not only doubling the C, but also halving the output impedance. I guess the trade off there is phase shift vs. loop gain. So that becomes a begin design from scratch kind of thing - I guess the right thing to do is break it away from this board development and treat it as a separate project, build and analyze an actual prototype.

Comment: Maybe, increase the value of R3 to compensate? Good point about the gate input C, I missed that...

Comment: Have measured **74HCU04** at lower frequencies than 21MHz: output resistance was many hundred ohms, often over 1000 ohms at the half-Vdd bias point. Where output swings up near Vdd, or swings down near GND, output resistance does fall below 100 ohms. These figures are dependent on Vdd. A single gate should have sufficient gain, even at 21 MHz. (unless you're Vdd is really low). You can drive another HCU04 gate directly with oscillator output - as a buffer. TI sometimes recommends replacing R3 (200 ohms) with a capacitor - same value as C2 at these high frequencies.

Comment: @CaptainKirchhoff maybe look at this device: https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/sn74lvc1404.pdf?ts=1598882895111&ref_url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.com%2F and my basic website on driving and understanding crystals: http://www.stades.co.uk/XTAL%20Oscillator/XTAL%20Oscillator.html

Comment: Perusing those links. This is a retro-computing project, no SMD is permissible, only through hole components... 5V supply vs. some lower voltage should help out.

Comment: You could re-package the chip to make it look retro LOL

Comment: Like a can oscillator visually? Perhaps repurposed? Or simply a piggyback PCB with the discrete parts on it, same footprint as the cans. Then an actual can oscillator would alternatively plug right in, if and when I can find some. One could epoxy and decorate that too!

Answer (score 2):

The feedback resistor turns the inverter from a digital circuit into an analog amplifier circuit. Trying to get a square wave output is like converting the analog amplifier into a digital inverter, so compromising the goal of the feedback resistor establishing an operating point for analog operation.

A square wave output contains the odd harmonics of the fundamental frequency. These harmonics compete with the fundamental to have the crystal vibrate at third or fifth overtones (harmonics in crystal world).

Propagation delay from the amplifier input to output is converted to a phase shift when frequency is accounted for. The higher the frequency, the greater the phase delay for a given propagation delay. This means that the crystal network must supply greater than 180 degree phase shift.

RS (including Rout) and C2 provides this phase shift.

For best frequency stability, the output of the amplifier should be sinusoidal, but a saturated sine wave ( usually called trapezoidal) will guarantee oscillation. All that is needed is a loop gain greater than 1. That is why most (if not all) Pierce oscillators are are squared-up by a following  inverter or Schmitt triggered inverter.

The [SN74LVC1404](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/sn74lvc1404.pdf?HQS=dis-dk-null-digikeymode-dsf-pf-null-wwe&ts=1690857632531&ref_url=https%253A%252F%252Fwww.ti.com%252Fgeneral%252Fdocs%252Fsuppproductinfo.tsp%253FdistId%253D10%2526gotoUrl%253Dhttps%253A%252F%252Fwww.ti.com%252Flit%252Fgpn%252Fsn74lvc1404) contains all the items necessary for a good Pierce oscillator.

Making the Pierce oscillator have a square wave output is ill advised.

Answer (score 1):

Given the price of basic integrated oscillators, I think the discrete approach is overkill. Whether you want to save space on the board, BOM cost, or improve reliability - integrated oscillators win unless your application is rather niche.

As for what you want to try: sure, it will do what you expect. It may be unexpectedly power-hungry, or hard to start in some conditions. Suddenly a “simple” oscillator may turn into an R&D project.

Are you prepared to validate it for mass production? You’d need to test it in a temperature chamber, across chips from several lots, and for startup over the full range of supply rail slew rates expected in service. A flaky oscillator can be such a serious troublemaker that I would think twice.

TI has not done tests on that design that you’d need to play it safe - and they say as much in the small print. Ultimately, performance verification across operating conditions would be your job.

Of course what “safe” is depends on the application too. For a cheap toy I wouldn’t think twice to do what you suggest. Kids can be surprisingly good at finding workarounds  - wiggle the power switch just right to get it to work, etc.

I love such “hacks” for hobby projects, retro-engineering, and such. Otherwise - stick a can there and forget about it :)

Comment: Yes, it's a supply chain issue. 21.47727 MHz crystals are plentiful from my sources, not so much 21.47727 MHz oscillator cans. If I do special order the cans, it will be huge cost difference.

Comment: There is a *ton* of programmable oscillators. DigiKey and other value-added distributors will program them for whatever frequency you want. No need for special order. Just your basic NCNR (non cancellable non returnable) order.

Answer (score 1):

The crystal generates a sine wave (because the mechanical oscillation has this form); adding additional inverters will not change this, and might prevent proper oscillation.

You must use an unbuffered (analog) inverter for the crystal, and you must add an inverter or buffer to get a digital signal out of this. If you want to minimize the component count, use an integrated crystal driver like the [SN74LVC1GX04](https://www.ti.com/product/SN74LVC1GX04).

Comment: Thanks, but the generated sine wave is at the output of the crystal PI network, this is the input not the output of the gate. You could say, the buffer output is an imperfect square wave, that is both because it's unbuffered (74HCU part) and because of the significant loading of the PI network. You can see the drastic effects of PI loading in the examples in the TI sheet, where R3 (Rs) is reduced to zero ohms.

Comment: In any case, it seems like adding an extra inverter doesn't buy very much improvement. So far, reading replies, it seems to me the output could be made more robust by adding the extra gate, increasing the value of Rs, and decreasing the value of C1 to compensate for the added gate input C. The device you linked to, shows unbuffered inverters used as output buffers - another IC. I think now, even the one inverter circuit should be prototyped and tested before going straight into a board design. Thus it is also time to look holistically at the entire design for clock alternatives.

Comment: All inverters are integrated in a single IC.

Comment: "You could say, the buffer output is an imperfect square wave, that is both because it's unbuffered (74HCU part)". Actually it is the other way around. The *amplifier* output is an imperfect sinusoid. The closer to being a sinusoid the better as long as it keeps oscillating.@CaptainKirchhoff

Comment: It's a part I would definitely use if SMD were allowed in my design. I may use it for other boards, thanks

Answer (score 1):

No, don't parallel the inverters that drive the crystal.

Use one inverter for the crystal.

Have the output of that single inverter go to only to the input of second inverter and use that as a buffer for actual output.

This will amplify the possibly sinusoidal waveform to almost square wave which should be good enough for many purposes.

For the rest of the 4 unused inverters, you can utilize them in almost any way you wish for further buffering, in series or parallel.

Comment: Yes, that is now the plan for testing, when I have those parts in hand. I worried about the buffer because a lot of sources tell you to use a Schmidt input gate for that.